# Hibernate jpa initialize all proxy in object

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I am trying to serialize an map of object which in turn can contain hibernate proxy. Does JPA or hibernate have something that will initialize all proxy, or will I have to track each object and initialize them specifically and then serialize.

The map contains 15 keys so its a little huge to track each one and initialize them

Comment: FYI Implementation details (proxies) are nothing to do with JPA. Totally Hibernate specific